# Small web Q&A page - JSP or HTML? 1 page or several?

Tags: html, jsp

I've been tasked with a small web flow. I need to ask a series of questions, then stop them or send them to a specified URL. I envision each line below shown by itself:

- Q1. If Yes goto URL, No goto Q2

- Q2. If Yes goto URL, No goto Q3-7

- Q3-7 Any Yes goto Stop page, all No goto Input page

- Input customer name, Next

- Print Preview - show all 7 Q&A, customer name and current date, let user print, then Next to final URL

So my questions are, should I have each of these be a separate JSP pages with a Form carrying the answers as hidden? Or should I put them all on one HTML page, and hide/display the questions using JavaScript (it would only appear they are moving page to page)? Either way I'll use JavaScript to validate the questions.

This is an internal-use only thing, and no data is saved. It will be hosted on a Tomcat server with other Java apps running, so JSP's are not a problem - I'm just wondering if its overkill.

Comment: Are you already working in an existing app that uses a framework of some sort?

Comment: We have other apps (Grails, JEE, Struts), but this will be new, stand-alone code not tied to anything else. Just some quick validation questions before we send them to a completely separate URL.

Comment: If there is no anticipated churn, and its really only a front-end app,  I would go with HTML/JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd approach this issue from a maintenance standpoint. How often do you think there could be changes to the questions? If your boss calls you in and wants to see every Q in the app, printing one HTML page would be easy enough for him/her to do themselves.

If there was no saving of data, I would go one with the one page approach to keep it simple and easy to manage.

Comment: Questions should rarely change once established. Users want the questions served individually, as listed line-by-line above, so they will only see what is listed on that line. After all Q's answered, the last Print page will show everything (non-modifiable).

Comment: It could really go either way... if questions were going to change a lot (including change in order), individual file would be the best approach. Michael-O is right, it would be a lot cleaner. imho, if you're using JavaScript either way, cut down on your work and put them all in one page.